# Is putting asynchronously different keys in an HashMap dangerous?

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency

(Don't judge the design, be mercyful)

I have a `Map<String, String>` that I need to populate with sub-maps from asynchronous calls. I am using `map.putAll(dataMap)` to insert each sub-map into the main map.

However, the asynchronous part is making me kinf of nervous. The reason is, I know that I won't attend to insert the same key twice (it is a sure fact), but I don't know if the fact that I insert data asynchronously will trigger concurrency mechanism.

Should I use a `ConcurrentHashMap` to be sure, or there are no risks with inserting into a classic `HashMap` asynchronously because I know I won't insert the same key twice ? Or is there a third object that I don't know of, that would fit the job perfectl ?

Comment: If multiple threads are writing to your map, then whether there are duplicate keys or not, you must make that thread-safe (by synchronizing all the accesses to the map, or by using a concurrent map). Now, maybe this is ensured already, but you posted no code, so we have no way of knowing.

Comment: Having no guarantee on how the HashMap is handled internally (maybe data is reorganized for efficiency reason; likely more memory is allocated after a threshold and data is rewritten. Who knows?) I would definitely use a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: If multiple threads are adding different keys it is still dangerous.

Comment: Got the point, welcome `ConcurrentHashMap`, do as you please.

Comment: with ConcurrentHashMap also you can corrupt your map if you are not checking for the key's presence before. Map gives you putIfAbsent and computeIfAbsent methods to do that